# Using For Loop Variables to Choose an Array Item in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a very simple question that I cannot find the answer to. I am trying to plug an array of x and y values through an equation, and fill an array with the answers. The error in this code is that the arrays don't accept numbers because "error: 'Range' is not convertible to 'Int'". How would I deal with this? This is done with Xcode 6.01 in swift playground. Thanks!

```
let x = [5.0,2.0,43.0,1.0,5.0]
let y = [62.0,2.0,43.0,1.0,4.0]
var answers=[Double]()
var current:Double = 0

for numbers in [0...4] {
    current = 1800*x[numbers] + 1600*y[numbers]
    answers.append(current)
} 

println(answers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A range is simply noted by `a ... b` or `a ..< b` (depending on whether the last
element is included in the range or not). Therefore

```
for numbers in [0...4] {
```

should be

```
for numbers in 0...4 {
```

without the square brackets, or better

```
for numbers in 0 ..< x.count {
```